# Location Based Access To SharePoint Online Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, security

Currently, there is an IP address location restriction applied in Azure to prevent access to all of our O365 tenant.  Access to our tenant from outside of our organisation is disabled based on an IP address range.  We would like to implement a more granular approach to external access.

We want to make only 1 site collection in SharePoint Online externally available.  How can this be implemented while retaining the restriction for all other sites and the rest of O365?

Comment: I don't even see how it's possible to have "an IP address location restriction applied in Azure to prevent access to all of our O365 tenant".  Can you elaborate on how this is implemented?

Comment: In the old Azure Portal there are options to set a block for all access outside a specific IP address range. The ip range can be set to inside the organisation only. Obviously this defeats the big purpose of external sharing but some organisations are that restrictive.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. You might have to set up some sort of proxy or gateway in Azure to intercept traffic and perform that logic. But I don't really know how you'd implement that. Good luck!

Comment: Please up vote in [user voice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/18808996-enable-ip-security-at-site-collection) for this. if we get 100 vote, Microsoft may consider implementing this.